# Hide show different divs and show all with button

Tags: javascript

I have 4 divs that each have a button , when a button on div is clicked it should hide that div. Then there is button at top called show all which will show all hidden divs again below is all the code show button , JS script and the four div boxes which should hide when button clicked on them and show all boxes again when show button is clicked

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm mt-3" id="show"><i class="fe fe-eye"></i> Show all</button>

<script type = "text/javascript" >
                    function show(elementId) {
                        document.getElementById("id1").style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById("id2").style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById("id3").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("id4").style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById(elementId).style.display = "block";
                    }
            </script>

<div class="card project-card" id="id1">
            <div class="card-header">
                    Bookmarks</strong>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm ml-3" onclick="show('id2');"><i class="fe fe-eye"></i></button>
            </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  body text here  
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card project-card" id="id2">
            <div class="card-header">
                    Bookmarks</strong>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm ml-3" onclick="show('id2');"><i class="fe fe-eye"></i></button>
            </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  body text here  
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card project-card" id="id3">
            <div class="card-header">
                    Bookmarks</strong>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm ml-3" onclick="show('id2');"><i class="fe fe-eye"></i></button>
            </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  body text here  
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card project-card" id="id4">
            <div class="card-header">
                    Bookmarks</strong>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm ml-3" onclick="show('id2');"><i class="fe fe-eye"></i></button>
            </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  body text here  
                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you post what you've tried already?

Comment: tried multiple things but got nowhere

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and show what you have tried. Nobody is going to write code for some imaginary buttons and div's we can't see. And the objective here is to help you with your code, not to be a free code writing service. Poor attempts shown will get you more help than no attempts

Comment: added what ive tried

Comment: OK...that's a bit better...now show the basic html structure that includes those `id`s

Comment: added the html in comment

Comment: OK....better...but I don't see 4 divs and a show all button. Don't need all the inner part of them and certainly don't need the server side code. Just the basic div's and buttons is all that is needed. Ideally we should be able to run your code with the html shown and try it out and that creates a reproducible example

Comment: hey i've added all the code and stripped out the server side stuff apologies for delay kept messing up the formatting

Answer (score 0):

Simply set `div`'s display to either `block` or `none` to hide it.

```js
let show = document.getElementById('show-button');
let divs = document.getElementsByName('container');
let hideButtons = document.getElementsByName('hide-button');

show.onclick = () => {
    divs.forEach((d) => d.style.display='block');
}

hideButtons.forEach((b) => {
    b.style.display='block';
    b.onclick = () => b.parentNode.style.display='none';
});
```

```html
<button id='show-button'>Show</button>
<div name='container'>
  <button name='hide-button'>Hide 1</button>
</div>
<div name=container>
  <button name='hide-button'>Hide 2</button>
</div>
<div name=container>
  <button name='hide-button'>Hide 3</button>
</div>
<div name=container>
  <button name='hide-button'>Hide 4</button>
</div>
```